# Join two tables multiple times?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a query with multiple joins and I just can’t seem to get it.
I have two tables custallocns and debtortrans.
custallocns has two columns transid_allocfrom amd transid_allocto that join table debtortrans  column debtortrans,id which I want the results into one column.
The code below is what I am trying, I have commented out the second join in the code as it will not work with both joins.
I have also tried to use them as alias cannot seem to get that either.
The one with the custallocns.transid_allocfrom  produces the debtortrans.transno  that are credits and the custallocns.transid_allocto produces the debtortrans.transno  that are invoice numbers I need to combine into one column.

```
 SELECT
                `debtortrans`.`transno`,
                debtortrans.type,
                custallocns.datealloc,
                debtortrans.id
FROM
                `ts_demo`.`custallocns` `custallocns`
INNER JOIN `ts_demo`.`debtortrans` `debtortrans` ON (
                `debtortrans`.`id` = `custallocns`.`transid_allocfrom`

/*INNER JOIN `ts_demo`.`debtortrans` `debtortrans` ON (
                `debtortrans`.`id` = `custallocns`.`transid_allocto`
)*/
)
WHERE
                debtortrans.trandate >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
AND debtortrans.trandate < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND debtortrans.settled = '1'
AND debtortrans.type BETWEEN '10'
AND '11'
```

Desired result:

```
 transno type allocdate id
     720   11  8/1/2016 12873
     721   11  8/1/2016 12876
     722   11  8/1/2016 12889
     723   11  8/1/2016 12891
    7419   10  8/1/2016 12872
    7421   10  8/1/2016 12875
    7427   10  8/1/2016 12882
    7432   10  8/1/2016 12887
     728   11  8/2/2016 12987
     729   11  8/2/2016 12989
    7470   10  8/2/2016 12988
    7471   10  8/2/2016 12990
     731   11  8/3/2016 13053
    7436   10  8/3/2016 12945
    7437   10  8/3/2016 12946
    7438   10  8/3/2016 12947
```

Comment: In second `INNER JOIN` simply use different alias for table `debtortrans` f.e `debtortrans2` and then modify your conditions in `WHERE`.

Comment: You use equal aliases, just change one of them

Answer (score 0):

In second `INNER JOIN` simply use different alias for table `debtortrans` f.e `debtortrans2` and then modify your conditions in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
                `debtortrans`.`transno`,
                debtortrans.type,
                custallocns.datealloc,
                debtortrans.id
FROM
                `ts_demo`.`custallocns` `custallocns`
INNER JOIN `ts_demo`.`debtortrans` `debtortrans` ON (
                `debtortrans`.`id` = `custallocns`.`transid_allocfrom`)

INNER JOIN `ts_demo`.`debtortrans` `debtortrans2` ON (
                `debtortrans`.`id` = `custallocns`.`transid_allocto`)

WHERE
debtortrans.trandate >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
AND debtortrans.trandate < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND debtortrans.settled = '1'
AND debtortrans.type BETWEEN '10'
AND '11'
```

Comment: Tried with no luck what do I need to do with the where conditions?

Comment: Some error message? You have to edit your `WHERE` conditions according to your requirements. Your desired result doesn't make sense, what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I you want join two column you need a inner join two time on the same table  using proper alias

```
SELECT
                `debtortrans`.`transno`,
                debtortrans.type,
                custallocns.datealloc,
                debtortrans.id
FROM `ts_demo`.`custallocns`
INNER JOIN  `ts_demo`.`debtortrans`  as a ON  a.`id` = custallocns`.`transid_allocfrom` 
INNER JOIN  `ts_demo`.`debtortrans`  as b ON  b.`id` = `custallocns`.`transid_allocto` 

WHERE debtortrans.trandate >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
AND debtortrans.trandate < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND debtortrans.settled = '1'
AND debtortrans.type BETWEEN '10'
AND '11'
```